# Saving .sql queries as .sql text file

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting

Beginner's question: I am learning SQL and the book says 'SQL queries can be created as an SQL script which can be saved as a plain text file with a `.sql` file extension.' presumably this is done in Notepad but how do I save it as a `.sql` script please?

Comment: save as filename.sql - done

Comment: change the file type to .sql , so the file name becomes filename.sql from filename.txt .

Comment: Hi Amand, thank you but I guess didn't make my question clear enough: when I have created the query in Notepad I want to save it as a .sql file but Notepad does not give me the .sql option in its list of 'save as'  choices. Bw patrick

Comment: Thank you Amand. When I attempt to Save As the notepad document, .sql is not a saving option. BW Patrick

Answer (score 5):

To save a file as sql file in notepad - save the file as "yourFile.sql" as in the below picture.

Make sure to select "All Types *.*" instead of "Normal text file (*.txt)"! Else it will be saved as script.sql.txt.

[image: Screenshot of how to save sql file from notepad]